# SQL delete rows after a select query with a limit

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I would like to delete all but the user's most recent 20 tests from a table that has multiple users in it.

attempt 1:

```
DELETE FROM tests WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tests WHERE user_id = 38 ORDER BY test_timestamp DESC LIMIT 20, 100);
```

attempt 2:

```
DELETE FROM tests WHERE user_id = 38 ORDER BY test_timestamp DESC LIMIT 20, 100;
```

Are there any changes that I can make either of the above samples to work or do I need to use PHP to setup a rowcount variable to work around my offset issue?

Comment: What was the result of attempt 2?

Comment: #2 error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 100' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do this using a `join`:

```
DELETE t
    FROM tests t JOIN
         (SELECT tt.timestamp
          FROM tests tt
          WHERE t.user_id = 38
          ORDER BY tt.timestamp DESC
          OFFSET 19 LIMIT 1
         ) tt
         ON t.user_id = tt.user_id and t.timestamp < tt.timestamp;
```

The two more "obvious" methods are not supported by MySQL.

- MySQL does not support `OFFSET` in the `LIMIT` clause for `DELETE`.
- MySQL does not support operations in the `WHERE` clause on the table being modified (without adding additional complication to the query).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DELETE FROM tests 
WHERE tests.user_id = 38
and tests.ID in (SELECT id 
FROM tests t
WHERE t.user_id = tests.user_id
ORDER BY test_timestamp DESC LIMIT 20, 100);
```

Comment: I received the following message when trying the above: #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' (My version is 5.6.33-log) Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

For attempt 1, this is the correct syntax

```
delete from tests
where the primary key field in 
(select the primary key field 
etc
)
```